# Join two panda dataframe with duplicate value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, join, duplicates

I have two tables

masterblok:

```
BLOCKID PLANTINGDATE  PLANTED_HA
   A001    01-JAN-08       13.86
   A002    01-JAN-08       13.24
   A002    31-MAR-18        1.99
   A003    01-JAN-08       14.76
   A003    31-MAR-18        2.48
```

pest_perperiod: (note that there is FIELDCODE other than A002)

```
FIELDCODE      PERIOD
     A002  2019-01-01
     A002  2019-02-01
     A002  2019-03-01
     A002  2019-04-01
     A002  2019-05-01
```

I want to join two dataframe so that for each data in pest_perperiod will have one or many corresponding PLANTINGDATE (like cross join in SQL) so I can calculate retention rate since active month for each BLOCKID and PLANTINGDATE

i tried using: (vice versa)

```
pest_perperiod.join(masterblok.set_index('BLOCKID'), on='FIELDCODE')
```

returned error because duplicated value still exist, how to do this?

Comment: try `past_period.merge`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you just want `merge`

```
pest_perperiod.merge(masterblock, left_on='BLOCKID', right_on='FIELDCODE')
```

output:

```
  BLOCKID PLANTINGDATE  PLANTED_HA FIELDCODE      PERIOD
0    A002    01-JAN-08       13.24      A002  2019-01-01
1    A002    01-JAN-08       13.24      A002  2019-02-01
2    A002    01-JAN-08       13.24      A002  2019-03-01
3    A002    01-JAN-08       13.24      A002  2019-04-01
4    A002    01-JAN-08       13.24      A002  2019-05-01
5    A002    31-MAR-18        1.99      A002  2019-01-01
6    A002    31-MAR-18        1.99      A002  2019-02-01
7    A002    31-MAR-18        1.99      A002  2019-03-01
8    A002    31-MAR-18        1.99      A002  2019-04-01
9    A002    31-MAR-18        1.99      A002  2019-05-01
```